# Open a specific workspace on i3 when launching a specific app

Tags: i3-wm

This week, I finally deciced to write in my i3 config file. Since I use firefox a lot I defined a shortcut for it (`bindsym $mod+Shift+f exec firefox`) and assigned firefox to a workspace (`assign [class="Firefox"]$ws2`).

My question is: what can I add to the line `bindsym $mod+Shift+f exec firefox` so that when I open firefox, the focus changes to the corresponding workspace (here, `$ws2`)?

Comment: To change to the workspace use `exec i3-msg "workspace $ws2"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change to specific workspace using `i3-msg` (in Your case):

```
exec i3-msg "workspace $ws2"
```

More general example from the i3 documentation website:

Documentation: https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html

```
# Start iceweasel on workspace 3, then switch back to workspace 1
# (Being a command-line utility, i3-msg does not support startup notifications,
#  hence the exec --no-startup-id.)
# (Starting iceweasel with i3’s exec command is important in order to make i3
#  create a startup notification context, without which the iceweasel window(s)
#  cannot be matched onto the workspace on which the command was started.)
exec --no-startup-id i3-msg 'workspace 3; exec iceweasel; workspace 1'
```